# Straight Lines and Cordinate Geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

The Locus of the point $P$, such that sum of squares of its distances from  $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$ is $25$ units, is $x^2+y^2-4x-6y+k=0$. Then $k =$ ?

Comment: Tried anything yourself? The question could be worded better as well.

Comment: ^ @mistermarko, done.

Comment: $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=25$. Expand, and compare with the given equation.